# Add a startup script in macOS High Sierra 10.13.2

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, script

I have a weather station program that I would like to run automatically in Terminal when I log in.  I manually have to run this every time I log in.  This is the simple script I would like to automate:

```
cd desktop
cd cumulusmx
sudo mono cumulusmx.exe
```

(*mono asks for system password which is entered in on next line*)

```
password
```

I am sure this is simple, but I am just starting out in macOS after many, many years of being a Microsux user.  Any simple solutions?

Comment: If you need sudo, I don't see any way to do this short of storing your password in the script. Which is possible, but a bad idea idea for obvious reasons.

Comment: You could set up a launchdaemon to run the script, as launchdaemons always run as root. But then you wouldn't be able to actually interact with the weather station program, as it's stuck in a root shell.

Answer (score 1):

Testing this under **macOS Sierra 10.12.6**, I did not find it necessary to use the `sudo` *command* to run `CumulusMX.exe` using `mono`.

At a minimum, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* can be used in **Script Editor** to create an **AppleScript** *application* that you can add to your **Login Items**.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cd $HOME/Desktop/CumulusMX; /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/mono CumulusMX.exe"
end tell
```

To use the  *example* **AppleScript** *code*, copy and paste the *code* into a new document in **Script Editor** and then save it as an application, e.g.: **Cumulus MX**

Then add **Cumulus MX** to: **System Preferences** > **Users & Groups** > **$USER** > **Login Items**

I’d like to mention that if I was doing this on my system the **CumulusMX** folder would not be on my Desktop, as IMO that’s not an appropriate place to put it. Also, in testing the  *example* **AppleScript** *code*, I did not find it necessary to use the `sudo` *command* to run `mono`, however if for some reason you need to do that, then additional steps would need to be taken but not recommended to automate.

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not include any *error handling* as may be appropriate/needed/wanted, the onus is upon the user to add any appropriate *error handling* for any *example code* presented.

Comment: Instead of Applescript, it would probably be simpler/cleaner to put the bash script itself in a *.command file. You can add a script with this extension to Login Items just like an app.